# error adding the second custom post type in wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress

In my functions.php, when I add codes for only one custom post type, it works fine but on adding another custom post type. it shows this error -

```
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/public_html/wordpress/wp-content/themes/mytheme/functions.php:83) in /home/public_html/wordpress/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 896
```

Why is it happening and what can be a possible solution ?

Comment: This error occurs when your server sends content to the client, then you try to modify the headers. Check your code to see if you used `echo` or printed anything on the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check line **83** of your **functions.php** file.
You probably have a closing php tag and new lines / whitespace after it. Remove any unnecessary white space after that closing tag.

Reference -- [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Kaloyan Ivanov ... I deleted extra white space, and it works now.